# I can't add a barButton Item to a navigationBar

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uinavigationbar

I Embedded a `ViewController` in a `UINavigationController` and after that, I added a new `ViewController` and connected it with a segue to the first `ViewController` that is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. then I wanted to add a `BarButtonItem` to that second view, but when I let go the bar button item in the top of the view next to the title, it inserts it at the button, and when I run the app it only shows the back button to the first screen and the title. (see the picture of how it looks when running and how it looks after inserting it at the top)[image: running the app in the iPad simulator][image: how the interface-builder looks after inserting the barbuttonitem to the top]

I hope you understood the question and you can help me!

thanks in advance!

Benji

Comment: go through this https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/04/14/adding-buttons-to-the-navigation-bar-with-storyboards/

Answer (score 0):

write this code in your viewDidLoad Method of controller where you want to add button

```
    let navBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
    navBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "side_drawer"), for: .normal)
    navBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 100)
    navBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openMessagingThread(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    let rightNavBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: navBtn)
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(rightNavBarItem, animated: true)
```

//Action for barButton

```
   @objc
func openMessagingThread(_ sender: UIButton)  {

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer!, but where does the openMessagingThread function come from? did you make the name? or is it a default name provided by apple?

Comment: its not default, he has added an action for UIBarButton its custom method.

Comment: ok, @AwaisKhan when I try to run the app it says by the line: navBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button(_:)), for: .touchUpInside).                       a error, the error message says: Use of unresolved identifier 'button'                              how can I fix that?

Comment: and change 
navBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button(_:)), for: .touchUpInside) 
to 
navBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openMessagingThread(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)